# Updating an nested array of object in setState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I have an array with multiple array which holds multiple objects and i want to  update any values in the object. I am able to update the object but my problem is whenever I update any object inside the array that parent array becomes object. I dont want to change the array to object. I am sharing my code and the output and expected output.

```
this.setState({
        tempArray: {
            ...this.state.tempArray,
            [lineNo]: {
                ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo],
                [pointNo]: {
                  ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo][pointNo],
                  x:parseInt(x),
                  y:parseInt(y)
                }
            }
          }
      },
      ()=>{
        console.log('callback tempArray',this.state.tempArray);
      })
```

If I change the first array x:7 to x:10 in the given array

```
[[{x:7,y:20}],[{x:50,y:60}],[{x:30,y:40}]]
```

My output is

```
[{x:10,y:20},[{x:50,y:60}],[{x:30,y:40}]]
```

But my expected output is

```
[[{x:10,y:20}],[{x:50,y:60}],[{x:30,y:40}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `[lineNo]` to an object. Try it like this:

```
tempArray: {
  ...this.state.tempArray,
  [lineNo]: [ // <--- [ instead of {
    ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo],
    [pointNo]: {
      ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo][pointNo],
      x:parseInt(x),
      y:parseInt(y)
    }
  ]// <--- ] instead of }
}
```

Comment: It is giving error.

Failed to compile
./src/dotLine/index.js
  Line 131:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  129 |                 ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo],
  130 |                 [pointNo]: {
> 131 |                   ...this.state.tempArray[lineNo][pointNo],
      |                          ^
  132 |                   x:parseInt(x),
  133 |                   y:parseInt(y)
  134 |                 }